# Windows starts unblocked after hibernation

Tags: windows-xp, hibernate

My Windows XP SP3 laptop sometimes starts with the session unblocked after hibernation. I mean, it doesn't ask for the password or anything. It starts directly with everything open as it was before hibernation.

The computer is attached to a domain, but this happens whether inside the domain network or outside.

Any ideas why this happens or how can I prevent it?
Thanks

**EDIT**
It's back again! In my new computer it's happening again. I'm pretty sure it's some group policy or something. Any idea why could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. Can you configure the power button of your laptop to hibernate it when pressed? You should be able to do that in the windows power settings. If so, try to lock the notebook and then use the button to hibernate. Not sure if it works, never tried it..

Comment: Well, maybe I'll try it later. Anyway, that doesn't tackle the problem. I would like to know why it happens, if at all possible.

Comment: Just changed my computer, so it's not longer an issue, I hope. Anyway, I think it had to do with some group policies in the domain, though my SysAdmin said he didn't know anything about it. His advice was to turn off hibernation alltogether.